# Converting SQL Query into Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following sql query that I need to convert into a Eloquent query I have the `lat` and `lng` fields in the user table. After some searching I found there is a `$user->whereRaw()` method on eloquent but that is as far as I got. I need to select all users within the 25 mile radius.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

It should work as `$user->whereRaw()` I think at least that is all I was able to find.

I need to mention that I am doing many queries before and after this, such as

```
$user->where()
$user->where()
Then this query needs to run
$user->where()
and finally
$user->get()
```

Comment: you can just perform normal query and hydrate the result into the model you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating data in this case, so eloquent builder its used mostly for known database attributes, you may need to use a raw expression in query. To create a raw expression, you may use the `DB::raw`, and mixed eloquent query will be:

```
$markersModel->select(DB::raw('users.id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( users.lat ) ) * cos(radians( users.lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( users.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
     ->where('distance', '<' ,25)
     ->orderBy('distance')
     ->take(20)
     ->get();
```

simple enough, and don't forget to import `use DB;`

**UPDATE**

Should not be a problem you can keep chaning the builder until finally you execute it with `get()` so this then will be:

```
$user->where()
$user->where()
$user->select(DB::raw('users.id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( users.lat ) ) * cos(radians( users.lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( users.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
     ->where('distance', '<' ,25);
$user->where()
and finally
$user->orderBy('distance')
     ->take(20)
     ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for that I should have mentioned that I was doing many queries before and after this and at the ending getting the results. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: no problem with that :) keep chaining eloquent builder until u finally exe with get(); @james

Comment: You changed it to 'tableneme.distance' in this second query is that correct? Or should it just be 'distance'? I will try this ASAP.

Comment: not only distance since that will throw ambiguous exception. you should add the table name that contains that column that you are trying to access!

Comment: Im am sorry, but I am confused. It is the user table, but there is no column 'distance'. I am storing the "lat" and "lng" in the users table and everything in the user table. There is no distance column I thought that was 'AS distance' was for.

Comment: You have aggreggated it as distance so now that column is availible since those aggregated data need to be stored in a new column or in your case you named it as distance, so thats right! just add users instead of tabelname!

Comment: I am getting the error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.distance' in 'where clause' (SQL: select ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( users.lat ) ) * cos(radians( users.lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( users.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from `users` where (`role_id` = 2 and `ban_user` = 0) and `users`.`distance` < 25)

Comment: Tried as just 'distance' as well with similar issue.